# Slide menu pushing the page and not get over the page

Tags: ionic-framework

I don't know why my side menu pushing the page on side and not getting over the page.

[image]

Thanks for your help

The menu.module.ts route and show the aPage. The menu page is the parent of the a page and is create just to make the side menu.

menu.html

```
<!-- Slide Menu -->
<ion-split-pane>
  <ion-menu contentId="content" slide="start">

    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">
            <ion-item>
              <ion-icon name="create" color="primary" slot="start"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label (click)="onLaunchModal()">
                Edit
              </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-menu-toggle>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>

  </ion-menu>

  <ion-router-outlet id="content" main></ion-router-outlet>

</ion-split-pane>
```

menu.modules.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'displayPage',
    component: InfoMenuPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'aPage',
        loadChildren: '../../pages/apage/apage.module#ApagePageModule'
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'displayPage/aPage',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

aPage.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>A Page</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

          Some Code

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Are you using iOS or Android? Because the behaviour you are experiencing is for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `type` property to set menu overlay :

example :

```html
<ion-split-pane>
  <ion-menu contentId="content" slide="start" type="overlay">
    ...
    ...
  </ion-menu>
</ion-split-pane>
```

Here is [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/menu).